# php exec don't run php script when i hit through browser OS X

Tags: php, macos, xampp

If i run following script through Mac OS terminal it php command run successfully

```
function run_backend_script($params = array())
{

  $cmd = '/usr/bin/php -v ';
  var_dump(shell_exec($cmd));
}

run_backend_script();
```

but when i hit through browser script there is no any output; command don't execute.

Note:-
I had installed XAMPP on MacOSX

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to the php.ini file in the XAMPP installation. Check if you are allowed to execute commands on it.

Comment: Can you please give me some more details about it

Answer (score 0):

Try another command, like `ls`. If it works, check the user permission on the `/usr/bin/php` binary. The `apache` or `www` user must be able to execute it.

Comment: i had tested it is working fine and displaying result. can you please tell me how to setup permissions for apache or www

Comment: you can add execute permission : `chmod +x /usr/bin/php`